# MySQL constantly "poofs" on production server

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

So I have a production server running Ubuntu with MySQL. No other services are running on the same server. It has 32GB of memory. MySQL service is set to restart always:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld
ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
TimeoutSec=600
Restart=always
RuntimeDirectory=mysqld
RuntimeDirectoryMode=755
```

dmesg doesn't report any relevant problems:

```
[Sat May 27 21:40:35 2017] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[Sat May 27 21:40:35 2017] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
[Wed Jun  7 02:48:53 2017] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[Wed Jun  7 02:48:53 2017] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
[Wed Jun  7 02:49:18 2017] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[Wed Jun  7 02:49:18 2017] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
```

I've disabled performance schema:

```
performance_schema = off
```

I ran badblocks, and got no errors:

```
Checking for bad blocks in non-destructive read-write mode
From block 0 to 31456238
Checking for bad blocks (non-destructive read-write test)
Testing with random pattern: done                                               
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

Same with fsck:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sdb1: clean, 375/1966080 files, 3268974/7864059 blocks
```

The error log seems to show a pretty clean shutdown:

```
2017-06-06T13:16:38.251027Z 67 [Note] Aborted connection 67 to db: 'ivr' user: 'root' host: 'ivr.teleline.co.il' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
2017-06-06T23:48:37.094552Z 0 [Note] Giving 16 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2017-06-06T23:48:37.094646Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2017-06-06T23:48:39.094785Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 15 remaining clients
2017-06-06T23:48:39.094867Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 6  user: 'root'

2017-06-06T23:48:39.094963Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 14  user: 'root'

2017-06-06T23:48:39.095017Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 18  user: 'root'

2017-06-06T23:48:39.095061Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 8  user: 'root'

2017-06-06T23:48:39.095156Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 7  user: 'root'

2017-06-06T23:48:39.095191Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 15  user: 'root'

2017-06-06T23:48:39.095226Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 10  user: 'root'

2017-06-06T23:48:39.095260Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 9  user: 'root'

2017-06-06T23:48:39.095295Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 16  user: 'root'

2017-06-06T23:48:39.095341Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 237  user: 'root'

2017-06-06T23:48:39.096103Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 11  user: 'root'

2017-06-06T23:48:39.096470Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 252  user: 'root'

2017-06-06T23:48:39.096757Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 12  user: 'root'

2017-06-06T23:48:39.096883Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 224  user: 'root'

2017-06-06T23:48:39.096928Z 0 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 13  user: 'root'

2017-06-06T23:48:39.097892Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2017-06-06T23:48:39.103817Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116325Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'auth_socket'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116369Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116375Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116383Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116394Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116400Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116412Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116420Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116427Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116457Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116465Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116470Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116475Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116480Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116611Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116628Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116634Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116639Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116644Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116649Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116654Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116659Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116664Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116669Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116674Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116679Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116683Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116709Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116715Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116720Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116725Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116729Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116734Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116739Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116743Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116748Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116753Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116758Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116762Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.116767Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2017-06-06T23:48:39.121885Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2017-06-06T23:48:39.122281Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2017-06-06T23:48:39.224242Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2017-06-06T23:48:39.224601Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 170607  2:48:39
2017-06-06T23:48:40.562889Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 8015926855
2017-06-06T23:48:40.563991Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2017-06-06T23:48:40.564012Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2017-06-06T23:48:40.564023Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2017-06-06T23:48:40.564028Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2017-06-06T23:48:40.565683Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2017-06-06T23:48:40.569582Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

The server does not have a public IP and is only accessible via VPN. Additionally, the bash history doesn't show any commands aside for ones I've ran.

Yet every so often, it just turns off, and doesn't come back on until manually restarted. I'm completely out of ideas, and am on the verge of simply rewriting the code to use a different database (e.g. MongoDB). Either that, or creating a cron job to run `service mysql start` every 5 minutes. What other options do I have?

Comment: in your .cnf adding in [mysqld] section expire_logs_days = 3 would provide you the opportunity to share the abnormal error log with this community. We may see come clues.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be looking at:

- trying to increase the logging level to see whether you may not have caught something you should have
- increasing logging and diagnostics on the system overall. The one thing I've discovered is that even if things sound unrelated something upstream can cause another program to fail downstream in an unexpected way. For instance, I used to work with a telephony system which used to crash when a part of the database seemed to experience IO throughput problems. Basically, what I'm advocating is running up the diagnostics to see whether there is a pattern to is happening. Of course, this means across the board (power, IO, network, hardware, memory, CPU, etc...). Of course, this also means that you cap the monitoring in such a way that it doesn't begin to interfere with what is happening on the system as well
- either way, I'd be scanning for malware and security incidents in case something may have happened. I've seen some really weird entry points for malware
- I'd be trying to isolate the problem further as well. Are you certain that there isn't something wrong with that machine itself (software or hardware)? Given the free hosting options out there and virtualisation technology it just seems strange that you wouldn't try this before possibly re-writing your program. Both options are quick and easy to test as well
- I'd likely try to create a simple script to log when the shutdown occurs over time. Something simple like a while loop that sleeps periodically but also checks when/if MySQL shuts down. Obviously this is only a few lines of code but will allow you to check if the thing occurs at regular time intervals
- I'd try re-configuring MySQL itself to see whether there is a limitation that you're not quite seeing
- I'd also try any compatible version of alternative database (but compatible) options in case it was something inherent to the program itself (too little information for me to go on based on what you've written). Saves you time as well since you don't have to re-write the program to see whether it is a genuine problem with what you've done or simply a configuration problem
- something else I'd be looking at are conflicting programs as well. For instance, if you work in the security or software space you'll realise you'll get some weird and unexpected problems from time to time. It's still possible in spite of what you may be thinking...
- I used to know people who used to do exactly what you've advocating. Namely, restarting the a program regularly to overcome difficulties in the software itself